# MLPAutoCompleteTextField suggestion table interaction issue

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield

Currently I'm using this third-party library in my project https://github.com/EddyBorja/MLPAutoCompleteTextField. This library is used to show the suggestion list based on user input.

I did setup the text field like this

```
    self.searchTextField = [[MLPAutoCompleteTextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 30)];
[self.searchTextField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
self.searchTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.searchTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
self.searchTextField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.searchTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
self.searchTextField.placeholder = @"Enter name to search";
self.searchTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;

self.searchTextField.delegate = self;
self.searchTextField.autoCompleteDelegate = self;
self.searchTextField.autoCompleteDataSource = self;
```

Implement the Datasource protocol as below

```
- (NSArray *)autoCompleteTextField:(MLPAutoCompleteTextField *)textField possibleCompletionsForString:(NSString *)string {
return @[@"AAA", @"BBB", @"CCC", @"DDD"];
```

When I input something to the text field, the drop down list was shown but when I tap on a cell in the drop down list, the list dissappeared without completing any words in the text field.

Anyone experienced this problem please explain to me where I was wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue awhile back. I happened to be using MLPAutocomleteTextField inside a UITableView, so all the touch events were likely intercepted by the tableview.

I worked around this issue by setting the autoCompleteTableAppearsAsKeyboardAccessory of my MLPAutocomleteTextField instance to TRUE to enable enable autocomplete as a keyboard accessory. This allowed me to select my autocomplete options. Hopefully this solves your issue as well. :)

Comment: Yeah eventually I was forced to use that solution and there seems to be no other solutions else :D

Comment: It is a descent workaround. Worked for me, for the MLPAutocompleteTextField inside a UIScrollView.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by subclassing my UITableViewCell, a little tricky but it's working for me:

```
#import "AutoCompleteTableViewCell.h"

@interface AutoCompleteTableViewCell()
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL selectedCell;
@end

@implementation AutoCompleteTableViewCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    self.selectedCell = NO;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (UIView*)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    UIView* hitView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    if (hitView != nil)
    {
        [self.superview bringSubviewToFront:self];
    }
    return hitView;
}

- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    CGRect rect = self.bounds;
    BOOL isInside = CGRectContainsPoint(rect, point);
    if(!isInside)
    {
        for (UIView *view in self.subviews)
        {
            isInside = CGRectContainsPoint(view.frame, point);
            if(isInside)
                break;
        }
    }
    if (!self.selectedCell) {
        self.selectedCell = YES;
        id view = [self superview];
        while (view && [view isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]] == NO) {
            view = [view superview];
        }
        UITableView *tableView = (UITableView *)view;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:self];
        [tableView.delegate tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    return isInside;
}
```

Then delegate method is called:

```
- (void)autoCompleteTextField:(MLPAutoCompleteTextField *)textField
  didSelectAutoCompleteString:(NSString *)selectedString
       withAutoCompleteObject:(id<MLPAutoCompletionObject>)selectedObject
            forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Comment: This method disable scrolling in the tableView because intercepts every touch. What I finally did was to send a NSNotification with selected text and store in a property in my VC every time a row was touched and in textFieldShouldEndEditing method (UITextFieldDelegate protocol) update UITextfield.text if my stored property has value. Hope It helps